# ruby regex to back engineer in order to find the route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

So I have this:

```
http://load-balancer:1234/users/123/convert_to_buyer/7654
```

and I want to convert to the original route without the digit into :

```
users/_/convert_to_buyer/_
```

I have this

```
url_with_digits.tr('^A-Za-z/\//_/', '')
```

but it's not goo enough --> `"http//loadbalancer/users//convert_to_buyer/"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use ruby's [URI](http://apidock.com/ruby/URI).

```
require 'uri'
url = URI.parse("http://load-balancer:1234/users/123/convert_to_buyer/7654")
result = url.path.gsub(/\d+/, "_")
#=> "/users/_/convert_to_buyer/_"
```

This way you don't need to have complex regex to handle different url schemas (before the path)

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1: `/users/convert_to_buyer`**

If you'd like to just convert the string to `/users/convert_to_buyer`, this will do it:

```
result = subject.gsub(/\/\d+|http:\/\/[^\/]*/, '')
```

On [the demo](http://regex101.com/r/sU5uF6), see the substitutions at the bottom.

**Option 2: `users/_/convert_to_buyer/_`**

If you're talking about replacing the digits with underscores and removing the head, chain it or do it in two steps:

```
result = subject.gsub(/\/\d+/, '_').gsub(/http:\/\/[^\/]*/, '')
```

**Explanation**

- With `/\d+` we match a forward slash and digits,
- `|` or...
- `http://[^/]*` the beginning of the url...
- and we replace with the empty string

Let me know if you'd like any tweaks.